# Geb testing: how to step through a test slower?

Tags: grails, functional-testing, geb

I have a very large Geb functional test in Grails that tests a big form with 25+ elements.  On the submit at the end of the test, it's not hitting the correct URL that I want it to in my Then: statement, it's hitting a different one.

How can I step through it slowly to see which if any elements I am not hitting?  Is there any way I can see why I'm not getting what I'm supposed to? -ryan

Comment: Try adding some `println` after you click an element to see if it succeeded? Very vague question

Comment: well... I can't re-post the entire form test because it is huge and very long, and it has org-sensitive data in it which I'd have to completely re-write just to post it here.    I just know at the end of the test (in the then: section), it's hitting a different url outcome than it's supposed, which would mean that something isn't firing.  Just wondering if there's a way to slow it down.

Comment: You mean make the test take longer between each action? Could just add some `sleep(1000)` after each action to sleep the test for a second.

Comment: ok I've never heard of that before.  Would I just add that in after a given line?

Comment: Yes, it's shorthand for `Thread.sleep(xxx)` so just stick them in whenever you want the test to wait a few seconds so you can observe what's going on. Only use it for debugging though, there's a host of problems related to using sleeps.

Comment: thanks I will try that and see if I can find if/where the test isn't hitting something.